# How to fetch data dynamically from an xml file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file that looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Options>
        <SampleRate>1000</SampleRate>
        <MaxStateSize>1</MaxStateSize>
        <MaxOutputSize>1</MaxOutputSize>
    </Options>

    <Observer>
        <Electrical>
            <Filter2 class="MatlabFilter">
                <FileName>tesla1.mat</FileName>
            </Filter2>
         </Electrical>
     </Observer>

    <CustomDefinitions>
        <MyRser class="OhmicResistance">
            <Object class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.02597518381655694900, 0.02513715386193249600, 0.02394715132636577100, 0.02325996676357371800, 0.02317075771456176400, 0.02277814077034603900, 0.02267913709322775700, 0.02258569292134297900, 0.02235026503875497600, 0.02222478423822949300, 0.02207606555239715500, 0.02198493491067361700, 0.02188144525929673300, 0.02167985791309091600, 0.02145797158835977700, 0.02137484908165417400, 0.02126561803424023600, 0.02124462299304301700, 0.02123310358079429400, 0.02126287857906075300, 0.02094998489960795500, 0.02073326148328196600, 0.02062489977511897100, 0.02038933084432985300;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </Object>
        </MyRser>

        <MyZarc1 class = "ZarcElement">
            <LookupOhmicResistance class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.00514195955695974370, 0.00529664894839530780, 0.00551630788423380920, 0.00564315318521097210, 0.00548602656854314720, 0.00581013032515952100, 0.00568539803363024480, 0.00559993408980672710, 0.00568126471231252940, 0.00555055893805056660, 0.00553252438800645470, 0.00533018726307717910, 0.00509464327131546690, 0.00493804793774787340, 0.00493109886771354610, 0.00477442697147319100, 0.00502025446307734210, 0.00487842931495043040, 0.00493811443745090660, 0.00515729571528417920, 0.00533726464325906100, 0.00593981588241465630, 0.00624109150199245260, 0.00689603850107461950;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </LookupOhmicResistance>
            <LookupTau class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.00063734182589317051, 0.00057789185722226211, 0.00049347290170957214, 0.00044472392739942722, 0.00046367738461651579, 0.00042508654901320510, 0.00044023991357759556, 0.00044357425217429899, 0.00042351365487481847, 0.00042064833809841269, 0.00042058843579174227, 0.00041492786364805096, 0.00040118819045609395, 0.00038561142394963408, 0.00037747031839295342, 0.00038856437977947608, 0.00044028413845948800, 0.00041943961777239272, 0.00048448584895609926, 0.00057788915932770971, 0.00047928926455149246, 0.00041669287910303676, 0.00038539468637880899, 0.00031735513697831374;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </LookupTau>
            <LookupPhi class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    1.07974864719212200000, 0.99348199898848211000, 0.87098335853931330000, 0.80024470701232853000, 0.80000000000000171000, 0.80000000000000038000, 0.80000000000000260000, 0.80000691369860855000, 0.80000000000000060000, 0.80000000000000027000, 0.80004367531484710000, 0.80000000000000149000, 0.80000000000000060000, 0.80000000000000249000, 0.80000000000000071000, 0.81779623001734880000, 0.80000000005521332000, 0.81111396956650339000, 0.81011503368816196000, 0.81230494833996914000, 0.80091506729318152000, 0.80000887696454015000, 0.79955578180021947000, 0.79857079231256578000;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </LookupPhi>
        </MyZarc1>

        <MyZarc2 class = "ZarcElement">
            <LookupOhmicResistance class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.03301452546632480100, 0.02957305472348599100, 0.02468616626865488600, 0.02186416025952706400, 0.01289985206743022800, 0.00816660308080110340, 0.00614478067084063380, 0.00525792478601965800, 0.00476592820730910300, 0.00458754759011727100, 0.00446897880675643960, 0.00468454174521149450, 0.00546732172234631280, 0.00563330158181225140, 0.00573737831209459540, 0.00607025493753720390, 0.00599470544834411390, 0.00637374896940332350, 0.00769547582533563430, 0.00930753356619881850, 0.01346675908515722000, 0.01684051438714963600, 0.01852739203814583700, 0.02219451736639845400;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </LookupOhmicResistance>
            <LookupTau class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.33635989830427793000, 0.28278374698293790000, 0.20670561210663510000, 0.16277316802313629000, 0.07298525375191647300, 0.03815615743074976500, 0.02451719292084131000, 0.01875641581778507100, 0.01630852098453383600, 0.01444778149059807100, 0.01353083053127584000, 0.01288716696808942500, 0.01409708819428110100, 0.01371252505120631800, 0.01432760299471728600, 0.01498271848043122500, 0.01622563803600479300, 0.01719588374486775300, 0.02298417293562926200, 0.03243196651297039500, 0.05525426980384628300, 0.09905004722829763300, 0.12094793594052324000, 0.16855204183666592000;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </LookupTau>
            <LookupPhi class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.70799773770539609000, 0.72250839021147018000, 0.74311351677009541000, 0.75501225182507614000, 0.74177842881577971000, 0.80122091069407952000, 0.86258087865252020000, 0.89734325213456811000, 0.91923534463767520000, 0.91834024872224662000, 0.93526886842710921000, 0.89875057203436626000, 0.82894875436479731000, 0.82264747106578762000, 0.81996236853572801000, 0.80358872652465718000, 0.81906893212010168000, 0.83493987333754394000, 0.79039503004349965000, 0.80763292126126807000, 0.80002267784885428000, 0.87508932730353728000, 0.91262265203087867000, 0.99421683622075130000;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </LookupPhi>
        </MyZarc2>

        <MyWarburgCotanh1 class = "WarburgCotanh" RCCounter = "10" WithCapacity = "False">  
            <Sigma class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.00019493534185688539, 0.00019493534185688539, 0.00019493534185688539, 0.00067426749346130913, 0.00106494971394849010, 0.00108151588850858910, 0.00099364136002325814, 0.00077950646290164086, 0.00058746266333470842, 0.00047915035146729013, 0.00041684830055908038, 0.00038907155296702889, 0.00085773887244337571, 0.00059930121703808173, 0.00009999999999863060, 0.00122801503737189690, 0.00061160314761842048, 0.00108680429208242790, 0.00090474553083427062, 0.00010000001120442429, 0.00085797449185355860, 0.00158984738214035730, 0.00195578382728375540, 0.00275129783846505670;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </Sigma>
            <Clim class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    184114.09294586902000000000, 184114.09294586902000000000, 184114.09294586902000000000, 296640.35877942020000000000, 155563.70463566060000000000, 161741.09030818491000000000, 274329.47505753755000000000, 365937.43100107106000000000, 471875.56453434512000000000, 574523.49228195997000000000, 500829.98327329860000000000, 500831.93837176822000000000, 516912.44569578546000000000, 14666.70203326588300000000, 500829.87961207400000000000, 171301.60968597961000000000, 15001.83580496977800000000, 11385.27633061551200000000, 39670.03821881797200000000, 15241.49130727929200000000, 45814.20857787308300000000, 6875.05990426292740000000, 6875.05990426292740000000, 6875.05990426292740000000;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </Clim>
        </MyWarburgCotanh1>

        <MyWarburgCotanh2 class = "WarburgCotanh" RCCounter = "10" WithCapacity = "False">  
            <Sigma class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.00836492574413456700, 0.00613129418512617630, 0.00295953737133426190, 0.00112795949294738170, 0.00037522002409440096, 0.00037581037146368275, 0.00068733685061351352, 0.00077015527398605326, 0.00080364831088865424, 0.00080077590753162026, 0.00082462291914824569, 0.00105712605279276560, 0.00100000000000000000, 0.00154529106500599240, 0.00145914207868891010, 0.00016323885946597442, 0.00101833795867687770, 0.00074589210831628103, 0.00010000004570686281, 0.00081464142917979561, 0.00010000043978881727, 0.00134063620710405860, 0.00196095409076167720, 0.00330947122914780620;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </Sigma>
            <Clim class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    23468.99221334158200000000, 18757.39143540290400000000, 12066.91833072997900000000, 8203.40569282026260000000, 9766.85232859530520000000, 13716.41747447804300000000, 20490.20448531251200000000, 23705.69491095333100000000, 22494.38807232537900000000, 19915.08394238330600000000, 16096.56074658045700000000, 10353.87296285772600000000, 8796.65707198722160000000, 239019.99718881631000000000, 12242.34469069729300000000, 18104.95029301897000000000, 213446.54566039098000000000, 239019.99118228391000000000, 12203.13852505865500000000, 44374.37961494550100000000, 12440.67207137969900000000, 60795.57175896296400000000, 84973.02160275452500000000, 137532.69517621450000000000;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </Clim>
        </MyWarburgCotanh2>

        <MyRC2 class="ParallelRC">
            <LookupOhmicResistance class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.00366188831554084640, 0.00562151834301598440, 0.00840419298203068030, 0.01001108960456029300, 0.00967486401762034100, 0.00939968391674490640, 0.00872919497962075870, 0.00822783378103364090, 0.00813506346266940770, 0.00779007715917680400, 0.00679257413068258020, 0.00606271929870643490, 0.00841078045910312150, 0.00791003775904466560, 0.01002849549145711600, 0.00997501477985486030, 0.00855965252090381410, 0.00609591267939118930, 0.00982352625138059080, 0.00964750941170980020, 0.00739790720395582920, 0.00115957740601912650, 0.00115957740601912650, 0.00115957740601912650;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </LookupOhmicResistance>
            <LookupTau class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    0.65173297869134739000, 0.65173297869134739000, 0.65173297869134739000, 32.59419722896010500000, 34.72865871720645000000, 34.47066564948234200000, 36.97952431512094100000, 36.93220799476522100000, 38.35431610344169000000, 34.09556741639196500000, 27.50565903985229400000, 26.75681820890759600000, 34.49371402438613600000, 43.24257987359646900000, 51.09778145546822300000, 45.00971082844134200000, 38.28699846139706900000, 31.07413008266951600000, 31.12255552828149900000, 28.80453236406994900000, 20.78359704561795200000, 0.10000010082754476000, 0.10000010082754476000, 0.10000010082754476000;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </LookupTau>
        </MyRC2>

        <MyOCV class = "VoltageSource">
            <Object class="LookupObj2dWithState">
                <RowState cacheref="Soc"/>
                <ColState cacheref="ThermalState"/>
                <LookupData>
                    1.90870643517178310000, 2.50000000000000000000, 3.33963686205606790000, 3.37337661754281680000, 3.43586504041013500000, 3.49016807881707790000, 3.53528751514386390000, 3.56403618253534700000, 3.58839269241070680000, 3.61254955876211210000, 3.64030000853381400000, 3.67403976401328690000, 3.72634636718430600000, 3.78643906777870100000, 3.82976171238624420000, 3.86849255596098420000, 3.90602553838471110000, 3.94815032185942980000, 3.99985799445857990000, 4.05436067638947860000, 4.09948011271626460000, 4.15677780397527390000, 4.20000000000000020000, 4.29396129570592680000;
                </LookupData>
                <MeasurementPointsRow desc="StateOfCharge">
                -5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
                </MeasurementPointsRow>
                <MeasurementPointsColumn desc="ThermalState">
                25
                </MeasurementPointsColumn>
            </Object>
        </MyOCV>

        <MyCellElement1 class="CellElement" observable="True">
            <ThermalState class= "ThermalState" cache= "True">
                <InitialTemperature>25</InitialTemperature>
            </ThermalState>
            <Soc class="Soc" cache="True">
                <MaxCapacity>3.0371</MaxCapacity>
                <InitialSoc>88.3</InitialSoc>
                <Measurementpoints>0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100</Measurementpoints>
            </Soc>
            <Children>
                <OhmicResistance ref="MyRser"/>
                <ParallelRC ref="MyRC2"/>
                <ZarcElements ref="MyZarc1"/>
                <ZarcElements ref="MyZarc2"/>
                <WarburgCotanh ref="MyWarburgCotanh1"/>
                <WarburgCotanh ref="MyWarburgCotanh2"/>
                <VoltageSource ref="MyOCV"/>
            </Children>
        </MyCellElement1>

    </CustomDefinitions>

    <RootElement class="SerialTwoPort">
        <Children count="1">
            <Pack ref="MyCellElement1"/>
        </Children>
    </RootElement>

</Configuration>
```

I want to fetch the lookup data for SOC and resistance in the MyRes class "ohmic resistance" in the root.child('CustomDefinitions'). How can I efficiently extract the two data sets and store them in arrays using python, as I have no experience with xml files.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I want to have the LookupData for ohmic resistance as well as 'MeasurementPointsRow' data stored in two diff arrays which I would be plotting later on

Comment: I am unable to fetch the data as it gives me an error when I try to do :                            
 for node in root.find('.//CustomDefinitions/OhmicResistance'):
     res = node.attrib.get('LookupData').                                                                                   It gives me the following error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I'm not sure what the target data looks like in the xml, so - again - what exactly does each of these two data points look like before you store them?

Comment: soc is the row vector in a 2d matrix and the lookupdata is the corresponding output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need something along these lines:

```
from lxml import etree
data = """[your xml above]"""

doc = etree.XML(data.encode())
soc = doc.xpath('//CustomDefinitions//MyRser[@class="OhmicResistance"]//MeasurementPointsRow[@ desc="StateOfCharge"]/text()')
lud = doc.xpath('//CustomDefinitions//MyRser[@class="OhmicResistance"]//LookupData/text()')
print(soc[0].strip()
print(lud[0].strip()
```

Output:

```
-5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105
0.02597518381655694900, 0.02513715386193249600, 0.02394715132636577100, 0.02325996676357371800, 0.02317075771456176400, 0.02277814077034603900, 0.02267913709322775700, 0.02258569292134297900, 0.02235026503875497600, 0.02222478423822949300, 0.02207606555239715500, 0.02198493491067361700, 0.02188144525929673300, 0.02167985791309091600, 0.02145797158835977700, 0.02137484908165417400, 0.02126561803424023600, 0.02124462299304301700, 0.02123310358079429400, 0.02126287857906075300, 0.02094998489960795500, 0.02073326148328196600, 0.02062489977511897100, 0.02038933084432985300;
```

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I need, if I want to plot the values, how can I store these 2 data sets in form of list considering there is a bunch of empty spaces

Comment: @HudaIftikhar Well, that's actually a different question, because it will depend on how exactly you want the list to look like. So, as per SO policy, the best way ti to post it as a separate question.